# How to run a java jar file which is in amazon s3

Tags: java, amazon-s3

How to run a java jar file which is in `Amazon S3`.

I have tried the following ways but no success. java jar `s3n://accesskey:secretkey@bucket`

```
java jar s3n://ASDSFSGSDFSKFLMSDGK:SDF8S7DF8AS787FYASDF77A@testingbucket/co.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be done. Since `Amazon S3` is a Storage Location it is not an `instance`. To run a jar it need a instance that is a Operating System.

To trigger a Jar File. Create a `EC2` instance and put it in a location and you can trigger it from a instance.

Comment: Is it possible to put the jar in S3 and trigger it using a shell script which runs on datapipeline.

Comment: Can you please try your suggestion and say. Let me try.